# Recursive Excel Spreadsheet Input to Applescript iMessage/SMS Messaging

Tags: excel, applescript

Ok, first time playing with Applescript today and after 6-7 hours am 'almost' there.  Basic premise of this script is that it should read two columns of data out of an Excel spreadsheet, one column is the phone number, the other is an alert.  It then writes the message into iMessage/SMS and delivers it.

I have it working off of a CSV well, and now trying to use the source Excel file to bypass the conversion step.  I am running into a classic number formatting issue where it reads the number into scientific notation and disrupts the phone number.  On converting it back to a normal string iMessage seems to choke on the formatting. (at this point I know its something simple I am missing.)

```
set phoneCol to "O"
set messageCol to "P"
set startRow to 3
set endRow to 5

set xlsFilePath to (path to desktop as text) & "test.xlsx"
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to open file xlsFilePath


repeat with thisRow from startRow to endRow
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set targetBuddyPhone to value of cell (phoneCol & thisRow) as string
        set targetMessage to value of cell (messageCol & thisRow) as string
    end tell

    set targetBuddyPhone to number_to_string(targetBuddyPhone)

    tell application "Messages"
        send targetMessage to buddy targetBuddyPhone of service "SMS"
    end tell
    delay 2
end repeat


on number_to_string(this_number)
    set this_number to this_number as string
    if this_number contains "E+" then
        set x to the offset of "." in this_number
        set y to the offset of "+" in this_number
        set z to the offset of "E" in this_number
        set the decimal_adjust to characters (y - (length of this_number)) thru ¬
            -1 of this_number as string as number
        if x is not 0 then
            set the first_part to characters 1 thru (x - 1) of this_number as string
        else
            set the first_part to ""
        end if
        set the second_part to characters (x + 1) thru (z - 1) of this_number as string
        set the converted_number to the first_part
        repeat with i from 1 to the decimal_adjust
            try
                set the converted_number to ¬
                    the converted_number & character i of the second_part
            on error
                set the converted_number to the converted_number & "0"
            end try
        end repeat
        return the converted_number
    else
        return this_number
    end if
end number_to_string
```

by contrast the following scrip to read the same variables from a CSV works with no issues at all, I did need to put a small delay in or I overran the buffer in iMessage.

```
set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Select the CSV file")

-- read the file contents:
set f to read theFile

-- break the file into paragraphs (c.f. rows)
repeat with row in (paragraphs of f)
    -- parse the row into comma-delimited fields
    set fields to parseCSV(row as text)
    -- now you have your data:
    set targetBuddyPhone to item 1 of fields
    set targetMessage to item 2 of fields

    tell application "Messages"
        send targetMessage to buddy targetBuddyPhone of service "SMS"
    end tell
    delay 2
end repeat

on parseCSV(theText)
    set {od, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, ","}
    set parsedText to text items of theText
    set my text item delimiters to od
    return parsedText
end parseCSV
```

Comment: Why don't you set the correct format number in Excel (#############), before reading the cell ? it will avoid the scientific notation upfront.

Comment: To avoid scientific notation value, you can use the `string value` property instead of the `value` property, like this --> `set targetBuddyPhone to string value of cell (phoneCol & thisRow)`

Comment: @jackjr300 - thank you, that worked perfectly.

Comment: The modified AppleScript code does work with an Excel contact list, however, it appears to send only to preexisting conversations; if the contact does not have an open message, the text will not send.

Does anyone have an idea how to get Messages to send to a long list of recipients who do not have open texts exchanges? Thanks in advance!